# Is there a way to use square bracket on environment variable in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I have an environment variable like as follows that works with docker-compose.yaml in relation to a springboot container:

```
    - name: pool.config[0].Number
      value: "2"
```

This works completely fine in docker-compose.yaml but not in yaml - it keeps giving error:

```
    a valid environment variable name must consist of alphabetic characters, digits, '_', '-', or'.', and must not start with a digit (e.g. 'my.env-name',  or 'MY_ENV.NAME',  or 'MyEnvName1', regex used for validation is '[-._a-zA-Z][-._a-zA-Z0-9]*')
```

In docker-compose it's fine with the square brackets in the key name, but in kubernetes deployment spec it's not permitting. How can I work through this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5315) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Relaxed-Binding-2.0#lists-1)

You should be able to use following binding for your case: `POOL_CONFIG_0__Number`